# Upper bound for the number of graphs up to isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory

As far as I know, there is no explicit $n$-formula for the number of non-isomorphic graphs with $n$ vertices. However, do we know if there is an upper bound for such quantity?

In particular, I am wondering whether said number is lower than the number of non-isomorphic subgroups of $S_n$.

Any idea/reference?

Comment: See Godsil Royle, chapter 2. They get $(o(1)+1)\frac{2^{\binom{n}{2}}}{n!}$